# Access properties of a type created by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code:

```
List<MultiServiceRequestMember> _memberList = new List<MultiServiceRequestMember>();
var type = Type.GetType(svc.NotificationClassName); <- this is a string of the class name.
MultiServiceRequestMember newMember = (MultiServiceRequestMember)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

_memberList.add(newMember);
```

The MultServiceRequestMember is a base type and I want to assign values to properties specific to `type`.  My question is: How do I cast newMember to type and access its properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I cast newMember to type and access it's properties?

You can't *cast* it, because you don't know the specific type at compile-time. If you did, you wouldn't need reflection in the first place!

You'll have to set the properties by reflection too:

```
// TODO: Checking that you managed to get the property, that's it's writable etc.
var property = type.GetProperty("PropertyName");
property.SetValue(newMember, "new value", null);
```

Comment: @EladLachmi: I'm quite interested how your code will look like with this approach. Maybe I'm missing something but I think you will end up performing same conditional logic as described in my answer.

Comment: @empi: It depends where the property names and values come from. We don't know that at the moment. If they're (say) stored in a database, there shouldn't need to be any conditional code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree with you - if there is a convention (e.g. map every field with the same name) or some external mapping definition exists (e.g. pairs field A maps to field B) it  is possible to do it. However, if mapping is completely arbitrary, then using reflection doesn't change anything.

Comment: All types inherit from the same base type and all the properties set here are well known at this point in the code. The initial definition is taken from an XML file. It might have been a good idea to add this to the initial question :) Sorry. Anyway... This approach works very well for me. Thank you.

Comment: @EladLachmi: Are all the properties present in the base type? If so, just cast to the base type instead, and you can do it all without reflection.

Comment: I can't cast to the base type since it is generic it goes Abstract class -> Generic class -> The types I'm creating via reflection. And the base abstract class has no properties. It's just used for creating list of the base type.

Comment: @EladLachmi: Do the properties depend on the generic type? If not, you might want to create a non-generic type between the abstract class and the generic class - or just move the properties up to the abstract class.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for the idea. I might just do that, since reflection is a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the code to look like this:

```
List<MultiServiceRequestMember> _memberList = new List<MultiServiceRequestMember>();
var type = Type.GetType(svc.NotificationClassName);
MultiServiceRequestMember newMember = null;
if (type == typeof(MultiServiceRequestMemberA))
{
    newMember = new MultiServiceRequestMemberA();
    //set specific properties
}
else if (type == typeof(MultiServiceRequestMemberB)) //etc.
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //throw or some default
}

_memberList.add(newMember);
```

However, it looks like code smell. I guess you're trying to initialize an object based on some other object (let's call it NotificationInfo). Then instead of code that looks like this:

```
if (type == typeof(MultiServiceRequestMemberA))
{
    newMember = new MultiServiceRequestMemberA();
    newMember.A = notificationInfo.A;
}
```

Maybe should think of following design:

```
class MultiServiceRequestMember
{
    public virtual void Initialize(NotificationInfo notificationInfo) //or abstract if you wish
    {
    }
}

class MultiServiceRequestMemberA : MultiServiceRequestMember
{
    public override void Initialize(NotificationInfo notificationInfo)
    {
        base.Initialize(notificationInfo);
        this.A = notificationInfo.A;
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to leave your previous code and just call Initialize.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, since it will not scale very well to N different classes. I already have the type as a string, no sense in not using that... Sorry.

Comment: The first approach is so smelly I wouldn't mention it at all. But the `Initialize` approach is much, much better.

Comment: OTOH, the smelly approach cannot be used at all if the set of potential implementors of base class is not known at all. The `Initialize` approach can.

Comment: @EladLachmi: if you want to set specific properties how would you set them without performing some conditional logic and checking the type?

Comment: I agree. The first approach is not a good one IMHO. The Initialize approach could work, but is not needed in my case. Thank you anyway.